# How to use Google Natural Language Processing Cloud API in Android

Tags: android, nlp, cloud, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

Hello I guys I want to use Google's Natural Language Processing Cloud API for my android Application. What are the steps for getting the reference to the api and what all things is to be downloaded and what are the steps to be followed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like it's more of a question for Google tech support / knowledgebase.

Answer (score 0):

We do have a sample currently published on our web site (cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/samples) with the source on github. You can use the sample but that it is in the process of being updated. It is not a step by step but more of a learn by example approach. Please take a look. It might be enough to unblock you now, and we're working on updating it as well.

Comment: Our sample is up to date now.